# Should posting answers on an old, already-answered, and inactive question be discouraged?

Tags: discussion, old-questions, answer-quality, late-answers, popularity

I have a question on Stack Overflow ([How does one remove an image in Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17665283)) which I asked over two years ago, and which was answered in a timely manner by a few people (timely meaning fast enough that it helped me too).

The thing is, this question is fairly popular and still draws answers - **most of them lower-quality duplicates** of the answer which was accepted over two years ago. There's not even any guarantee that these new answers are original content, instead of copies inspired by what's already there.

I'm referring specifically to all answers on that question below the 4-point threshold. The votes for the first two, timely answers are both above 100 points, so arguably they have been found useful by the community.

Should such low-quality and (arguably) not useful answers be discouraged in any way?

Comment: Yes. This is a fairly large problem on extremely popular questions. I often crowd-source delete votes to get rid of useless late answers before they have a chance to be upvoted into undeletable territory.

Comment: Feel free to ask for help getting rid of *specific* late, low-quality duplicate answers on *popular* questions in chat, especially the [SO close-voter room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). Just remember that it needs 3 20K users to delete-vote an answer, which must not be accepted and must score negatively.

Comment: Downvote and add a comment along the lines of "This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute."

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate.  Meta is getting as bad as SO itself.  The specifics of the question the OP refers do not matter, but rather the question in the title itself.  I often answer "old, already-answered and inactive question(s)".  I'm sick of seeing these duplicates in "Hot Meta Posts".  All I do on this site anymore is down-vote and vote to close questions.

Comment: I don't think late answer is discouraged.But duplicate/low quality answer always discourage does not matter post is new/old.

Comment: People look at stackoverflow answers years after the question was asked. Sometimes you have a better answer or important information to add that could be a big help to someone else. So I agree that the answer is to downvote and not to disallow answers to old questions.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is why we have a [Late Answer Review...](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers)

I don't think we should be discouraging late answers per se, but we should be discouraging low quality, duplicate answers regardless of when they're posted.

Unfortunately a lot of these slip through the review queue and need to be handled manually. Downvote, flag, and comment as needed.

If you notice an awful lot of these answers on a specific question, you can flag the question and request that it be ["Protected"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question) to prevent new users from posting additional answers.

Comment: As an aside, the rep-limit applied on protected questions (15) is really low, so it only works on those completely new. And anyway, you can also ask in chat, if you have a case.

Comment: @Deduplicator ya, the protected status could probably use some tweaking. It seems to help with spam, but doesn't do much for simple bad/dup answers

Comment: Agreed, sometimes things change and the accepted answer becomes incorrect, so there are cases where late answers are actually *exactly* what is needed. Low-quality duplicates on the other hand should obviously be removed.

Comment: I think putting these in the Late Answer Review queue could actually give them an undeserved/unnecessary upvote since the reviewer doesn't see the answer alongside others. So if the answer is inferior to the accepted one but still passable enough it may garner an unwarranted upvote.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan there's been a few requests to show the other answers in the late answer queue. It seems the the powers that be want the answers to be weighed on their own merits, which sort of makes sense, except that it doesn't account for duplicate answers.

Comment: @apaul34208 Makes sense. Almost got burned by that as well. Maybe as a compromise the page could display a note if there are already other answers to the question.

Answer (score 18):

The downvote tooltip indicates "This answer is not useful".

If an answer is just a "lower-quality duplicate" of another answer feel free to downvote, perhaps with a comment explaining why.

Answers that don't add anything new (in terms of information and/or clarity of explanation) lower the signal to noise ratio and are therefore worse than simply being "not useful" - being actively harmful IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Late answers are good when:

1. They provide a better answer than those existing.
2. They provide a useful caveat about a particular case the existing answers don't cover.
3. They in some other way add significantly to the information already on the page.
4. They provide updated information, and indicate that it is such (not saying that they are based on updates makes them both incorrect—they don't answer the specific question since the specific question was about the earlier state of the art—and unfairly suggests that good previous answers weren't good, saying they are updates is useful).

All of those cases should be encouraged.

An answer that merely duplicates existing answers, or which is simply bad, is a net loss whether the question is months old or a day old. That the question is old isn't really the issue, though the survivor bias of high-scoring old questions will just mean they have this happening more often.