# Should the bar be raised for Protected Questions?

Tags: discussion, protected-questions

A recent [comment exchange](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299612/1947286) got me thinking...

Should we raise the bar for [protected](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/06/new-protected-question-status/) questions?

Does the [current protection status](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question) work as intended?

Or should we perhaps:

- Raise the minimum reputation required to answer protected questions?
- Add some more text to the protected question banner, possibly indicating that questions can be protected to prevent low-quality and duplicate answers.
- Do something else?
- Just forget the whole thing and go out for waffles?

<sub><sub>Somewhat related:</sub></sub>

<sup><sup>[Prevent protection of questions when it would have no effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253132/prevent-protection-of-questions-when-it-would-have-no-effect)</sup></sup>

Comment: see also: [How many questions escape community protection because of reputation gained within checked question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242942/165773) "...protection criteria... is (to a large part) based on voting in questions intended to be protected - in _popular_ ones, and voting in these often is _anomalous_... softly speaking. As far as I can see, that makes it way too fragile."

Comment: hm. A while ago, I had a feature request... it was intended for a different site and was meant to serve somewhat different purpose but upon re-reading your question I thought something like that can actually apply to protected questions: [When there are many answers already, help me check that mine won't repeat others](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2562/168). "I would want that questions... <insert _protected questions_ here> have additional UI allowing me to review each of previous answers individually prior to posting my own..."

Comment: ...sort of the way to raise the bar that doesn't depend on reputation - the more answers pile on, the harder it gets to add a new one. Everyone can answer but they need to make _substantial effort_ to get there

Comment: This is easy to answer if you have the data. What is the minimum rep of the poster of an undeleted answer with at least one upvote to a protected question? If the number is 20 then raise it. If it's 10 then what exactly is protection doing? We're already good at removing spam, what is a bit amount of spam removal against a potentially fantastic answer?

Comment: Protected questions that end up featured in the "hot network questions" list typically require 100 reputation earned *on that site* to answer (the +100 bonus from associating an existing account doesn't count).

Comment: What problem is being solved with this? Do you have a set of protected questions that have received excessive answers from users with a different minimum reputation? What information or pattern led you to believe that changing the design of protected questions addresses an observed problem?